# Console application with two threads

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.scanner

I just want to print `learning...` as long as I enter 1

```
  package a;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    class main extends Thread {
        static String n;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        public void run() {
            n = reader.nextLine();
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
            (new Thread(new main())).start();
            n="5";
            System.out.println("1 = ON\n0 = OFF");
            while (n.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("Learning..");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you expect `while(n.equals("1"))` to loop while `n="5"`? You might also want to read up on multithreading and data races.

Comment: Well, when I didn't define it , it threw me an error.

Comment: I just want to be able to turn it off and on, Thats all.

Comment: It's pretty clear that you should set `n` to `"1"` and not `"5"`. Most consoles aren't designed to handle input and output in parallel though, so you'll probably run into some more problems.

Comment: I don't want the loop to start off right away though, I want a simple on and off, if I type 1 and hit enter it will print a whole bunch of learning.. if I type 0 it will stop, then if I type 1 again it'll start

Comment: Then nest two while loops within an infinite loop (`while(true){...}`) and have the first while loop be `while(n.equals("0")) { Thread.sleep(100);}` and have the second while loop be `while(n.equals("1")) { // print "Learning..." }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to stop start, it is always better to maintain two threads one for printing and other for taking input. Try with blow code. It is working fine for me.

```
  public class ThreadsStop {

    static String n="";

    class Printer extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(!n.equals(null)){

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    if(n.trim().equals("1"))
                        System.out.println("Learning..");

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

    }

    class Starter extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            while(true){
                System.out.println("1 = ON \n 0 = OFF");
                n= reader.nextLine();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ThreadsStop().start();

    }

    private void start() {

        new Starter().start();
        new Printer().start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in reading up on the Producer-Consumer pattern. You can take a look here http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html and try with something like

```
class main extends Thread {

// a thread-safe queue for decoupling reading and writing threads avoiding
// synchronization issues. The capacity of the queue is 1 to avoid reading (producing) a
// command without having handled (consumed) the previous before
private static final BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1);

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        String s = reader.nextLine();
        try {
            //if the queue is empty, adds the element, 
            //otherwise blocks waiting for the current element to be handled by main thread
            sharedQueue.put(s);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    (new Thread(new main())).start();

    System.out.println("1 = ON\n0 = OFF");
    while (true) {
        //will block till an element is available, then removes and handles it
        final String s = sharedQueue.take();
        if ("1".equals(s)) {
            System.out.println("Learning..");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This does seem like a nice solution - please consider adding some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - and provide explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: One thing though, It's not looping when input 1, it only does it once

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the given below code.

```
class main extends Thread {

    static String n;

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            n = reader.nextLine();
            if (Integer.parseInt(n) == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        (new Thread(new main())).start();

        System.out.println("1 = ON\n0 = OFF");
        while (n == null) {

        }

        while (n.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Learning..");
        }

        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below program, it will take your input and print it.

```
class main extends Thread {
    static String n;

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Enter n value ");
        n = reader.nextLine();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        (new Thread(new main())).start();
        n="5";
        System.out.println("1 = ON\n0 = OFF");
        while (n.equals("5")) {
            //System.out.println("Learning..");
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

The reason why your code is not taking input, before providing the input your main method executed, which means that program execution completed. I have done few modifications to your code. Now your code will take your input.